# Transform a list of dict to an simpler dict

Tags: python-3.x

I have list of dict like this:

```
[{
    'attr': 'bla',
    'status': '1',
    'id': 'id1'
}, {
    'attr': 'bla',
    'status': '1',
    'id': 'id2'
}, {
    'attr': 'bli',
    'status': '0',
    'id': 'id1'
}, {
    'attr': 'bli',
    'status': '1',
    'id': 'id2'
}]
```

I wan't to get a simpler results dict like this:

```
result = {
    'bla' : True,
    'bli' : False
}
```

If the two id have a `1` for  an attr, the value will be True. else, it will False.

I've tried with

```
for elem in dict:
        for key, value in enumerate(elem):
        # ???
```

But i don't see how to do. I've alos tried something like

```
if all( val == '1' for val in list ):
    # ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
dicts = [{
    'attr': 'bla',
    'status': '1',
    'id': 'id1'
}, {
    'attr': 'bla',
    'status': '1',
    'id': 'id2'
}, {
    'attr': 'bli',
    'status': '0',
    'id': 'id1'
}, {
    'attr': 'bli',
    'status': '1',
    'id': 'id2'
}]

# First run is to create all nessecary items in the 
# new Dictionary so i can use the and operator on them later.
newDict = {}
for dictio in dicts:
    for key, value in dictio.items():
        if key == 'attr':
            newDict[value] = True

# The second run uses the and operator            
for dictio in dicts:
    for key, value in dictio.items():
        if key == 'attr':
            tmpAttr = value
        if key == 'status':
            newDict[tmpAttr] = newDict[tmpAttr] and (value == '1')

print(newDict)
```

Have a nice day!